# PHP / Javascript loop using cookies - redirection

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

So I'm a little new to the whole Javascript / PHP thing.  It is indeed very fun coding with these two languages.  Right now if a user goes to chrisrjones.com they are redirected to chrisrjones.com/splash.php.  There are two radio buttons asking the user if they like splash pages or not.  Depending upon the users choice a cookie value is set to true or false.  Also another cookie is created called "visit" once the user clicks the "enter" button.

If you the user selects "YES" splash pages are stupid, they enter the site, but if the window / tab is closed in the browser they are presented with the splash page upon reload of the site.

If the user selects "NO" splash pages are stupid, they can not enter the site at all.

Is there a way to get the user to enter the site once either button is clicked? (there's gotta be a way)

Also is there a way to remember if a user selects YES and not redirect them.

The **index.php** file looks like the following

```
<?php
$cookie_splash = $_COOKIE['nosplash'];
$cookie_visit = $_COOKIE['visit'];

if ($cookie_splash == "false" || $cookie_splash == "" && $cookie_visit == "") {
    echo "<script type = text/javascript>";
    echo "window.location = 'http://chrisrjones.com/splash.php'";
    echo "</script>";
}

if ($cookie_splash == "false" && $cookie_visit == "true") {
    echo "<script type = text/javascript>";
    echo "window.location = 'http://chrisrjones.com/index.php'";
    echo "</script>";

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>chrisRjones.com</title>
<!-- default - stylesheets at the bottom override styles at the top -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="stylesheet.css" />

<!-- favicon -->
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />

</head>

<body>
<!-- cut for readablitiy -->
</body>
</html>
```

**splash.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>chrisRjones.com - Splash</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function valForm() {

    if(!document.getElementById('splash_false').checked && !document.getElementById('splash_true').checked  ) {
        alert('You either like splash pages or you don\'t choose one ...please');
        return false;
    }
}

</script>

<!-- Javascript radiobutton form validation END -->


</head>

<body>
<img src="<?php echo $path . $img ?>" alt="" width="640" height="auto"  />
<h1>Refresh the page to enjoy more pictures.</h1><br />

<p>
<form name="tosplashornottosplash" action="splash-process.php" method="post" onSubmit="return valForm()">
Splash pages are stupid.

<input type="radio" name="splash" id="splash_false" value="false" /> No
<input type="radio" name="splash" id="splash_true" value="true" /> Yes

<input type="submit" name="splashSubmit" onClick="return valForm(tosplashornottosplash)" value="Enter" />
</form>
</p>



</body>
</html>
```

**splash-process.php**

```
<?php 

setcookie("visit", "true"); // delete cookie when browser / tab / session is clossed

$splashvar = $_POST["splash"];

if ( $splashvar == "false" ) {
    // create cookie - nosplash 1
    setcookie("nosplash", "false", time()+3600); // expires in one hour
}
    else {
        // create cookie - nosplash 0
        setcookie("nosplash", "true", time()+3600); // expires in one hour
    }

echo "<script type = text/javascript>";
echo "window.location = 'http://chrisrjones.com/index.php'";
echo "</script>";

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>chrisRjones.com - splash-process</title>

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try removing that second if in the Index.php. It doesn't really do anything since they, the user, is already there.